# Android, clear X amount of Activities from the activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, activity-finish

how can I clear only a variable number of activities from the activity stack?

Lets say I want to clear 3 activities, I won't use `android:noHistory` in the manifest, I won't use a method to clear the whole stack

and maybe I could call `finish(); finish(); finish();` under a certain condition, but that doesn't seem right.

is there a known method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could register a `BroadcastReceiver` in the classes you want to finish, then send the broadcast when you want to finish them.

Answer (score 1):

Messy, but you can use getParent(). eg:

```
this.getParent().getparent().finish(); 
this.getParent().finish(); 
this.finish();
```

And if you wanted to do this to x number of activities, you could use a loop and a variable to trace back x number of parents.

Comment: This can work, messing around with the way intents were launched in certain scenarios was the better option